# Capturing a Chocobo early in the game

Tags: final-fantasy-10-2

I encounter Chocobos rarely at the start of a fight before they run away, in various regions such as Mi'hen Highroad, Calm Lands, Bikanel Desert etc. Based on the teams I'm facing, it should be a Medium size fiend.

Trying to set SP traps with Bird type a few times hasn't helped so far, nor have I captured one in my M-size traps. Is it possible to capture it during Chapter 1, and if so how should I raise my chances of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible to capture a Chocobo in Chapter 1 - I've captured them in Mi'ihen Highroad.  However, the Chocobo actually counts as an S creature, so you would need to use an S pod.  (And as far as I know, it doesn't have an assigned creature class so you would be unable to capture it with an SP pod.)